# Discord.py How to make something only available after something else

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py, accessibility

I want to make Yes or No only accessible after you Type !Version, Can you tell me How to do this? I cant figure it out. My Code makes Yes and No accessible every time.

````
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!Version'):
        await message.channel.send('Sure?')     
    if message.content.startswith('Yes'):
            await message.channel.send('This is the Version 1.0')
    if message.content.startswith('No')
            await message.channel.send('Okay')  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a message event, it's best if you use a command function decorator in order to allow a message to be sent after the command was run. Instead, by using `wait_for`, this will make your bot essentially "wait for" a required message to be sent. In your case, after running the command, the bot will wait for "yes" or "no" to determine what next it can send.

Here is an example implying a command and `wait_for` in your question.

```py
@client.command()
async def version(ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Sure?")
        msg = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=10,check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

        if msg.content.lower() == "yes":
                await ctx.send("This is the Version 1.0")

        if msg.content.lower() == "no":
                await ctx.send("Okay")
```